# jQuery Accordion - enlarging the box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using jQuery accordion to implement the similar features which http://flavors.me have. I've designed the palette which consists of text links which leads to text box, dropdown box etc..etc. What I need is when I click any link in the accordion, the entire box should be enlarged according to the  text boxes and other items in the accordion link.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/GXAYa/

Could anyone just modify the code to get that feature for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correct, this should solve the problem?

```
#boxtext {
font-family: Tahoma;
color: white;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: It should, but don't take my word for it